# How to wait for Angular Google Maps to append getGMap to the control object

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I've been trying to set up click event listeners on the `google.maps.Map` object that's created by the `ui-gmap-google-map` directive from the [Angular Google Maps library](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/).

I need to do this dynamically, so it seems (by my brief testing at least) that using the `events` parameter on the `ui-gmap-google-map` directive won't work (because it seems to "read" the parameter value only once, but maybe I'm wrong about that).

So I decided to use the `control` parameter, which augments the object named by the parameter value with the methods `getGMap` and `refresh`. Here is what my directive usage looks like:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="appCtrl.mapSetup.center"
                    zoom="appCtrl.mapSetup.zoom"
                    control="appCtrl.mapSetup">
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Finally, I'm loading the Google Maps API asynchronously, and relying on the `GoogleMapApi` service/promise (part of Angular Google Maps) to know when I can start safely dealing with the `google.maps.Map` object (e.g. adding event listeners etc.). Here is a small example of what that looks like:

```
// inside the AppController constructor, see the fiddle linked below
var mapSetup = this.mapSetup;
GoogleMapApi.then(function () {
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapSetup.getGMap(), 'click', function () {
        alert('hello');
    });
```

So when the page is loaded ([here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6jfjvu0/12/)), I get "TypeError: undefined is not a function" because the `mapSetup` object hasn't been augmented with `getGMap` or `refresh`. It seems like it should have been, based on my understanding of the documentation.

I wrapped the `addListener` call with `$timeout` (the Angular service) using a few hundred millisecond delay, and then it worked because the `mapSetup` object had by that time been augmented with `getGMap`.

Is there a way to avoid having to use `$timeout` with an arbitrary delay to wait until the `control`-specified object is actually augmented?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By my testing and by what I've read in the docs and in various issue comments, it seems that this (waiting for the `control` object to get augmented) is one of the things that the `uiGmapIsReady` service in Angular Google Maps was designed for.

My current understanding is that `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` should be used to wait for async loading of the Google Maps API and `uiGmapIsReady` should be used to wait for `uiGmap*` directives and all they entail (including `control` object augmentation) to complete. The naming says it all.

Here's [a new demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcbaphk2/2/). This demo's usage of `IsReady`:

```
IsReady.promise().then(function (maps) {
    var map1 = $scope.control.getGMap();
    var map2 = maps[0].map;
    alert(map1 === map2); // true
});
```

`IsReady.promise` ([source](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/develop/src/coffee/directives/api/utils/is-ready.coffee)) accepts an optional integer argument indicating (I'm pretty sure) the number of `ui-gmap-google-map` directives your page is using. It defaults to `1`. (If you happen to give it a "wrong" number, I believe there's a (remote?) possibility that the returned promise will never resolve.)

Comment: This answer looks much cleaner. Updating to the correct answer.

Comment: IsReady is now uiGmapIsReady as of Angular Google Maps v2.0

Comment: I confirm that the integer passed to `uiGmapIsReady`'s promise is the number of ui-`gmap-google-map` directive in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using vanilla JS and got everything to work with no headache. Angular Google Maps is a cool idea, but at least in my case, the issues outnumber the benefits.

After spending an hour or so on github and stackoverflow, I realised that the proposed solutions (like https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/308) were a hack of a hack, and since my task was just "display some markers on a map and center the map on them" I don't want to use a hack.

The gmaps documentation contains tons of examples (in vanilla JS) that can be used in an Angular app, copy + paste and you're done.

Again, this is my personal experience, might not be the same for you