# Refreshing map and markers with angular-google-maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

Hi I am using the angular-google-maps for my project. The html and js code is as follows

html:

```
        <ui-gmap-markers models="apartments" coords="'loc'" icon="'assets/images/map_icon_normal.png'" idkey="'_id'"
                     fit="'false'" click="click">


      <ui-gmap-windows show="'show'" >
        <div ng-non-bindable>{{streetAddress}}</div>

      </ui-gmap-windows>
    </ui-gmap-markers>



  </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Script: 
angular.module('myApp')

```
.controller('MapCtrl',
                    function ($scope, $routeParams, Map, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
 $scope.apartments = [];
 $scope.customIcon = "../../assets/images/map_icon_normal.png"

$scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: $routeParams.lat,
        longitude: $routeParams.lon
      },

      zoom: 5,
      bounds: {},
      events: {
        tilesloaded: function (map) {
          //console.log('tiles loaded');
          $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.mapInstance = map;
            //console.log(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
            $scope.searchbox.options.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds($scope.mapInstance.getBounds().getNorthEast(),
              $scope.mapInstance.getBounds().getSouthWest());

          });
        },
        idle: function(map) {

          $scope.map.refresh = false;

        },
        resize: function(map) {
          console.log('resize');
        },
        dragend: function() {

        }
      },
      markersEvents: {
        click: function(marker, eventName, model, args) {
          console.log('markerEvent click');
          $scope.map.window.model = model;
          $scope.map.window.show = true;
        }
      },

      window :  {
        marker: {},
        show: false,
        closeClick: function() {
          this.show = false;
        },
        options: {} // define when map is ready
      },

      control: {},
      refresh: function () {
        $scope.map.control.refresh();
      }
    }

    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (map) {

      $scope.getData(20, 0, map);

      map.visualRefresh = true;
      $scope.mapInstance = map;


    })

       $scope.getData = function(limit, offset, map) {
      Map.getApartments($routeParams.lat, $routeParams.lon, limit, offset).success(function (data) {
         ///----- I get undefined error here---
              $scope.map.control.refresh();



      });

    }})
}
```

I am not sure how to refresh the map with the new markers or even trigger an update to the map. I played around with 'control' and 'refresh' params of the ui-gmap-google-map but cannot get it to work.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I found the new refresh functionality, example: $scope.map.control.refresh({latitude: 32.779680, longitude: -79.935493});   but it doesn't work for me, did you managed solving this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `uiGmapIsReady` --- not `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` --- to wait for `control` objects to be augmented with their methods (such as `refresh`).

The `uiGmapIsReady` service provides a promise which resolves when all `uiGmapGoogleMap` directives have been fully initialized, while the `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` service resolves simply when the Google Maps JS API has loaded.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27179215/402749) for an example of using `uiGmapIsReady`. And of course, don't forget [the docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api).

Regarding how to get updates to your models property on the scope to cause updates to your map, your code example needs to be fleshed out and cleaned up to help you there. (For example, what is the resolution of `getApartments` doing to update `$scope.apartments`? Or maybe asking that question is itself the answer?) Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/228n5106/1/), it might help you in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Try `dorebuildall` attribute.

```
<ui-gmap-markers 
    models="apartments"
    coords="'loc'"
    icon="'assets/images/map_icon_normal.png'"
    idkey="'_id'"
    fit="'false'"
    click="click"
    dorebuildall="true">
        <ui-gmap-windows></ui-gmap-windows>
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

More details at: http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/

Comment: Can you create a plnkr for this?